# Google Calendar Api - Python - Sync Token, Refresh Token

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

Environment details

- OS: MacOS Catalina
- Python version: 3.6.9
- pip version: 19.3.1
- `google-api-python-client` version: 1.7.11

Steps to reproduce

1. It states here https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/sync that a GoogleJsonResponseException will be returned in Java if a sync token can not be returned. Currently I have the following:

```
events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', syncToken=sync_token, pageToken=page_token).execute()
except Exception as e:
    if 'code' in e and e.code == 410:   #sync token was invalidated, full sync required
        #clear token, call full sync
```

How are invalidated sync tokens handled in python?

2. Is there python documentation that shows the client library automatically refreshing the access token after .execute()? For example, doing the following appears to show the client library automatically refreshing my access token:

```
credentials = pickle.loads(user.google_api_credentials) 
print(credentials.valid) #false
event_results = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', singleEvents=True).execute()
print(credentials.valid) #true after calling .execute() in the line above. Does this confirm automatic refreshing of access_token?
```

Can someone confirm if using the google-pi-python-client will automatically refresh the access tokens without requiring extra code?